# Why git log graph of merged branch from GitLab was inverted?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, git-flow, merge-request

[image: git graph]

As you can see in the image, feature branch number `668` has been merged into `dev` branch. But why the git graph appears like `dev` branch was merged into branch number `668` instead?

This behavior seems to happen only when do a merge request from GitLab.com. It does not happen when manually merge in a local machine.

Thanks!

**EDIT: Added git graph from GitLab.com**
[image]

This is my GitLab merge request setting:
[image]

Comment: did you run `git pull origin develop` to sync the branch?

Comment: @TheGeorgeous Yes, I already did.

Comment: That's why you have the merge from develop to your branch. If you don't want merge commits when you pull, you can either add `--rebase` when you pull or set `pull.rebase` to true in your gitconfig

Comment: @TheGeorgeous Thanks for the quick reply. I think it happened before I was pulled `dev` branch in my local machine. As you can see in my new screenshot above which is on GitLab.com so it is not related with my machine, so maybe it is the GitLab's behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something fishy with the two successive merge commits `merge branch dev into 668-*` and `merge branch 668-* into dev`.

Try running :

```sh
# you don't need the full history : '-5' will limit the log view to 5 commits
git log --oneline --graph -5 dev
```

You should see a sequence of commits and merge, where at some point `dev` was fast forwarded to `668-*`.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to update to everyone. After a certain amount of time, everything is back as it should be. I don't know what happened too.